# How to sync Nexus 4 and Nexus 7?

Tags: sync, nexus-7, nexus-4

I have the both Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 devices. I want them to have the same (at least similar) list of installed applications and their settings. How can I synchronize them, so that I do not need to install and set everything up two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android lets you backup settings & data for installed apps, but doesn't have a straightforward way to sync the actual installation of them. If you prefer not to manually search/install each app from the device itself (it gets really tedious) you can do what I do:

1) Go to https://play.google.com/apps to view the apps which are already installed on one device. Select the app you want to transfer over to view it's details page.

[image]

2) If the app is compatible with both devices (most probably will be but not all) click the button that says <kbd>INSTALLED</kbd>.

[image]

3) Select the other device where you want to install it and click <kbd>INSTALL</kbd>.

[image]

You'll still have to repeat this for each app you want to carry across, but I've found it to be much easier to do it with a mouse in a web browser than searching/installing

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that. The reason I asked is that I first installed apps in my Nexus 4. Then I got my Nexus 7, and surprisingly, I find that it automatically installed the apps. But later on, when I installed new apps. in Nexus 4, nothing happened to Nexus 7.